# pytorch simple custom recurrent layer extremely slow

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I implemented a very simple custom recurrent layer in pytorch using PackedSequence. The layer slows down my network in the order of x20. I read about slow down on custom layers without using JIT, but in the order of x1.7, which is something I could live with.

I am simply indexing the packed sequences per sequence and performing a recursion.
I have the suspicion some of the code is not executed on the GPU?

I'm also grateful for any other tips how to implement this type of RNN (essentially not having a dense layer, without any mixing between features).

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import PackedSequence

def getPackedSequenceIndices(batch_sizes):
    """input: batch_sizes from PackedSequence object
    requires length-sorted sequences!
    """
    nBatches = batch_sizes[0]
    seqIdx = []
    for ii in range(nBatches):
        seqLen = torch.sum((batch_sizes - ii) > 0).item()
        idx = torch.LongTensor(seqLen)
        idx[0] = ii
        idx[1:] = batch_sizes[0:seqLen-1]
        seqIdx.append( torch.cumsum(idx, dim=0) )
    return seqIdx


class LinearRecursionLayer(nn.Module):
    """Linear recursive smoothing layer with trainable smoothing constants."""

    def __init__(self, feat_dim, alpha_smooth=0.5):
        super(LinearRecursionLayer, self).__init__()
        self.feat_dim = feat_dim
        # trainable parameters
        self.alpha_smooth = nn.Parameter(alpha_smooth*torch.ones(self.feat_dim))
        self.wx = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(self.feat_dim))
        self.activ = nn.Tanh

    def forward(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, PackedSequence):
            seqIdx = getPackedSequenceIndices(x.batch_sizes)
            ydata = torch.zeros_like(x.data)
            for idx in seqIdx:
                y_frame = x.data[idx[0]] # init with first frame
                # iterate over sequence
                for nn in idx:
                    x_frame = x.data[nn]
                    y_frame = self.alpha_smooth*y_frame + (1-self.alpha_smooth)*x_frame # smoothing recurrence
                    ydata[nn,:] = self.activ(self.wx*(y_frame))
            y = PackedSequence(ydata, x.batch_sizes) # pack

        else:  # tensor
            raise ValueError('not implemented')
        return y
```